# Не получается добавить элемент в массив

Tags: android

в AndroidStudio если пишу :
String[] mass = new String[5];
mass[0] = "TEXT"; 
то подчеркивает и пишет unexpected token. 
Хотя если так:
String[] quest = {
            "France",
            "Sweden",
            "Poland"
    };
то работает.

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;

public class CapitalsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button nextButton;
    private Button answerOne;
    private Button answerTwo;
    private Button answerThree;
    private Button answerFour;
    private int index = 0;
    private TextView questionTextView;

    String[] quest = {
            "France",
            "Sweden",
            "Poland"
    };

    String[][] answ = {
            {"Paris", "Rome", "Moscow", "York"},

            {"Warsaw", "Stockgolm", "beijing", "Kuala-Lumpur"},

            {"Warsaw", "Bagkok", "London", "Phuket"}
    };

    /* private Questions[] questions = new Questions[]{
             new Questions(R.string.questions_france, "Париж"),
             new Questions(R.string.questions_sweden, "Стокгольм"),
             new Questions(R.string.questions_poland, "Варшава")
     };
     */
    private void updateQuestion() {
        // int question = questions[index].getTextResId();
        if (index == quest.length) {
            index = 0;
        };
        questionTextView.setText(quest[index]);
        answerOne.setText(answ[index][0]);
        answerTwo.setText(answ[index][1]);
        answerThree.setText(answ[index][2]);
        answerFour.setText(answ[index][3]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.capitals);

        questionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);

        nextButton = findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // index = (index + 1) % questions.length;
                index++;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Где в этом коде что то, связанное с `String[] mass`? ведь именно с ним у вас проблемы или чем вам надо помочь в коде, который вы прикрепили к вопросу?

Comment: наверное пытается инициализировать в полях класса

Comment: Вместо массива String[] quest пытаюсь написать String[] mass = new String[5]; mass[0] = "TEXT"; 
и не выходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переносите инициализацию и обращение к элементу массива в `onCreate()`. То есть это

```
mass = new String[5]; 
mass[0] = "TEXT"
```

Объявить сам массив можно в полях класса, так как он нужен вам для `updateQuestion()`